# Generate unique id in JavaScript when the method Date.getTime and Math.Random been overwirte

Tags: javascript, algorithm, guid, uuid

I have a script running on sites. When I'm trying to generate unique id, like suggests in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript), it sometime fails to do so because it seems like the sites are overwrite the functions Date.getTime and Math.Random.
Is there a way to generate a unique id in this cases?

Note: I need to use the unique in the server side

Comment: *"the sites are overwrite the functions Date.getTime and Math.Random"*  ? Really ?

Comment: What kind of scripts are you speaking about ? Userscripts ? Or one of your libraries ? If you made a library, you probably should assume the basic environment hasn't been too much broken, this is the responsibility of the script user.

Comment: I'm talking about script that wrote, I'm not using any libraries in this script

Comment: Based on `Math.Random`, it looks like you may be talking about Java, not JavaScript.  Can you re-tag if this is the case?

Comment: You should create your uuid's server side. Those are faking Math and Date (who else should overwrite this?) will also be able to fake any another approach.

Answer (score 1):

For client-side purposes the following should be enough:

```
var uniqueId = (function() {
    var id = 0;
    return function() {
        return id++;
    };
})();
```

Comment: @Anibas then generate it server side, otherwise you are trusting the client.

Answer (score -3):

Wow!

If your words are true and no way to fix code on sites:
Add Jquery and call $.now() - it will return timestamp for you.

but I am 90% sure you do something wrong from scratch, reconsider your code on sites

Comment: jQuery.now is using Date.getTime. now: function() { return ( new Date() ).getTime(); }